# MYSQL - Why am I getting Syntax errors in what should be a perfectly sound chunk of code?

Tags: mysql, triggers

### SOLVED

### Among mintor syntax errors, I had to declare a delimiter at the beginning! All sorted! :)

I'm trying to create a trigger that will ensure that checkindate is < checkoutdate in my 'booking' table. From all of the examples/tutorials that I can find online, I feel like my solution should be working... Any thoughts?

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS booking_bi_trg;
CREATE TRIGGER booking_bi_trg
BEFORE INSERT ON booking
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE inDate DATE;
DECLARE outDate DATE;

IF (inDate > outDate) THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "Error!";
ENDIF;
```

Errors that I'm getting:

Line 6: Missing semicolon... even though there is one where it should be

Line 7: Declare is not valid at this position (but online examples beg to 
differ)

Line 9: If is not valid at this position (.... what?!)

Line 11: Extraneous input found, expected end of input.

Comment: is this the complete code?

Comment: This is the complete code for the trigger that I'm trying to write. There was another .sql provided by my course convenor to create and populate the tables - but that all runs without issue.

Comment: BEGIN should have a corresponding END. Plus if your trying to access the value you have set for the InDate and OutDate, you should use NEW.COLUMN_NAME_HERE  and do the comparison.

Comment: @Dr.Stitch So if I change the syntax to IF (NEW.inDate > NEW.outDate) it should work?

Comment: i suppose, plus put the "END" at the last part of the code.